# Правила для ударений

Tags: орфоэпия, недопустимая-метка, акцентология

Насколько мне известно (и на это указывает ответ на вопрос "[Правила постановки ударений](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/6860/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)"), в русском языке **практически нет** правил для расстановки ударений.

Откуда же тогда берутся **правильные** ударения в орфоэпических словарях?
Раз в десять лет собирается "Тайный Совет Десяти" и решает, КАК правильно:
**пЕтля** или **петлЯ**?

Если нет правил, то как понять, как правильно?

Comment: Если не воспринимаете правильного ударения, заучивайте.

Answer (score 2):

В русском языке ударение подвижное, разноместное. Чётких правил постановки ударений очень мало. Приставка рос-, например, всегда ударная (рОспись). В глаголах прошедшего времени женского рода единственного числа (понялА) ударение ставится часто на окончание -а, но далеко не всегда. Так что главный помощник в изучении русского ударения - орфоэпический словарь или словарь ударений.

P.S. В русском языке женские и мужские имена можно подвести под правило. Так, женские имена имеют ударение на предпоследнем слоге (Марина, Инна, Ия, Полина, Валентина Оля и т.д.), в мужских именах всё немного по-другому. Маленькие мужские имена, как и женские,  имеют ударение на предпоследнем слоге (Коля, Женя, Володя), а большие - на последнем (Михаил, Антон, Валентин, Сергей). Но есть и исключения (Юрий и др.)

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос слишком общий / обширный, чтобы дать ответ на него в сжатой форме. Да, жёстких правил для расстановки ударений нет, но имеются основные закономерности, которые охватывают большую часть слов русского языка и позволяют его носителям безошибочно определять ударение даже в большинстве незнакомых слов. Также имеются основные тенденции, которым, как правило, подчиняются переходные формы и исключения.

Чтобы понять эти закономерности и тенденции я посоветовал бы почитать/посмотреть замечательные лекции великого советского и российского лингвиста А.А. Зализняка об ударениях в словах русского языка.

[Вот пример](https://elementy.ru/nauchno-populyarnaya_biblioteka/432371/Iz_russkogo_udareniya) текстовой расшифровки одной из его лекций.

[Здесь](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cdowOJcJ9_c) другая видео-лекция.

Кроме этого, поиском можно найти множество захватывающих лекций А.А. Зализняка по самым разным вопросам лингвистики.

Comment: Спасибо, очень интересные статьи! Но опять же, у меня возникает побочный вопрос - какова процедура утверждения "правильного" ударения? Потому что даже с таблицами в первой статье у моего "интуитивного" понимания ударений есть расхождения, причем я с альтернативой никогда не сталкивался. Например, включИшь указано как норма, но я за всю жизнь ни разу не слышал, чтобы так говорили (всю жизнь в СПб живу, если это вдруг важно). Из-за этого у меня возникает ощущение, что в словари иногда попадают какие-то "местечковые" нормы (ведь великий *я* не может ошибаться).

Comment: @Amomum А часто вам приходилось слышать: "нужно вклЮчить свет"? Конечно, вам кажется, что удобнее всего запоминать ударение для каждой словоформы (падежа, склонения, числа, рода), ведь носитель языка способен запоминать исключения тысячами. Я не лингвист, поэтому просто выскажу свою точку зрения иносказательно. Язык — наш общий дом, и задача лингвистов — помочь обустроить этот дом так, чтобы нам и нашим детям было удобнее в нём жить. Доверять их профессионализму или нет — это уровень вашего права и вашей (гражданской) ответственности.

Comment: там было именно "включИшь", не в инфинитиве. По существу вы, конечно, правы. Но когда я готовился к ЕГЭ по русскому, я вынужден был узнать достаточное количество "правильных" ударений, которые казались мне совершенно неестественными. И выбора, кроме как зазубрить их, не было, потому что никаких правил не давалось. Или когда я в метро вижу плакаты с "правильными" ударениями. Скорее всего, это не проблемы лингвистов.

Answer (score 0):

Фактически — орфоэпические нормы устанавливаются учеными, которые исследуют речь носителей языка, акцентологические явления и другие факторы, в конечном счете влияющие на словарное ударение в том или ином слове.

Действительно, никаких универсальных правил русского ударение не существует. Тем не менее, слово может менять свою акцентологическую парадигму, и как раз эти изменения поддаются некоторой систематизации, в результате которой мы можем говорить об акцентологических законах.

Таким образом, если вы хотите владеть орфоэпическими нормами, необходимо узнавать произношение слов с помощью словаря. Других надежных путей нет.

Comment: А существует какая-нибудь формальная процедура для изменения словарного ударения? Например, столько-то процентов населения должны ставить ударение именно так? Или "норма" просто кочует из словаря в словарь, хотя в живой речи она уже не применяется?